# Strange console behaviour while using smbclient

Tags: linux, samba

I need to get file list from samba share using smbclient (mount is not allowed for several reasons) and later download some of them;

When I execute the command

```
 smbclient -U my_username \\\\server_address\\somedir my_password -с "tarmode;recurse;prompt; mget *"
```

everything is ok - it downloads files and **gets back to my usual console session**.
But when I execute the following

```
 smbclient -U my_username \\\\server_address\\somedir my_password -с "ls"
```

it does not execute `ls` - it just logs in and shows me the **smbclient** console.What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls` is not a valid [smbclient](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smbclient.1.html) command.

You could change that `ls` to a `dir` or you can precede it with a `!`  as `!ls` to issue it as a shell command via smbclient.